# Simplify an If/Else statement with null checks

Tags: php, if-statement

I'd like a way to simplify an if/else statement that concatenates two values together, but also checks for null values before using the variables.

For example:

```
if (isset($A,$B)) {
  $C = $A . $B;
}
elseif(isset($A)) {
  $C = $A;
}
elseif(isset($B)) {
  $C = $B;
}
```

Before concatenating `$A` with `$B` I need to make sure neither are `NULL`.  If they both contain a value, then I want to assign the concatenation to the variable `$C`.  If either value is null, then I want just one value assigned to `$C`.

The above works fine when I only have two variables, but what if a third variable `$D` were added and I needed to concatenate into `$C` and still check for nulls.  Then I would need to check first for ABD, then AB, then BD, then A, then B, then D.  It will get really unruly.

So how can I simplify the code and allow for more variables to be added in the future if necessary?

Comment: Instead of each being a different variable, could you push each value to an array and use `implode()` to do the concatenation for you? That way you wouldn't have to check. What is present in the array would be concatenated. What's not present wouldn't be concatenated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following:

```
<?php
  $a=NULL;
  $b="hello ";
  $c=NULL;
  $d="world\n";
  $all = implode(array($a,$b,$c,$d));
  echo $all;
?>
```

This prints

```
hello world
```

without any errors. It is an implementation of the comment that @wor10ck made - but he didn't seem to follow up with a full answer / example and I thought his suggestion was worth fleshing out.

**EDIT** for people who don't read comments - @Keven ended up using

```
$result = implode(array_filter($array));
```

which is a nice robust way to remove the NULL elements in the array.

Comment: @Floris Could you please explain why I do not need to check for `NULL` values when imploding? Or atleast why `NULL` values don't throw an error when being inserted into this array?

Comment: @Keven I am not sure but I suspect that the conversion of `NULL` to string produces an empty string, and then concatenation is not a problem.

Comment: In order to handle NULL values I decided to use the `array_filter` function.  So something like `$all = implode(array_filter($array))` worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Keven - that is a nice improvement! I have included it in the answer - so people who don't read comments get the benefit of your new-found insight.

Answer (score 2):

```
$C = (isset($A) ? $A : '') . (isset($B) ? $B : '') . (isset($D) ? $D : '');
```

Answer (score 2):

You *might* find this usefull

```
$C = "";
$C .= (isset($A) ? $A : "").(isset($B) ? $B : "");
```

The question mark operator returns the left part before the : symbol if the statement is true, and right if false. Hoever i *think* that nesting statements in **if** block is more optimised.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// I assume $res is the variable containing the result of the concatenations
$res = '';

if(isset($a))
  $res .= $a;
if(isset($b))
  $res .= $b;
if(isset($c))
  $res .= $c;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$A = 'a';
$B = 'b';    

$C = '';
$C .= isset($A) ? $A : '';
$C .= isset($B) ? $B : '';
$C .= isset($D) ? $D : '';

echo $C;
```